# Не могу выложить веб-сервис на IIS

Tags: iis, веб-служба, развертывание

Есть веб-сервис (пара DLL-ок, сам сервис и еще пара файлов).
Чтобы выложить веб-сервис, я создал сайт в IIS, указал порт, в папку к этому сайту выложил все файлы веб-сервиса. Теперь я не могу понять как к нему подключить, и работает ли он вообще, так как просмотр (Browse Website) результатов не дал.

Подскажите, как довести "до ума" это дело так, чтобы можно было спокойно с другой машины подключиться по URL к этому веб-сервису?

Comment: а что именно происходит по browse?

Comment: "Невозможно отобразить страницу". Учитывая, что никаких веб-файлов типа асп или хтмл там нету, ошибке я не удивляюсь.

Comment: проверьте порт сайта. проверьте статус сайта в iis manager - сайт должен быть запущен. зайдите туда по http://localhost:port/ - iis покажет  подробную страницу об ошибках.